# How does SOFC work?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrons, molecular-structure, conductivity, electricity

The [Solid Oxide Fuel Cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_oxide_fuel_cell) is a particular case in which an oxide is used as a conductor. Once i've heard that oxides usually aren't good conductors but it turned out that a lot of oxides are conductors. What i am asking is :

1. How can i know if a oxide is a **conductor or not**?
2. If there isn't any conduction band since it's not a metal, how do the          **electrons** move and how does the SOFC work?

Thank you.

Comment: Not all conductors work by conduction of electrons - [*ionic* conductors are a thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionic_conductivity_(solid_state)). I think the most famous one is alpha phase of AgI. For oxides, off the top of my head I can think of [YSZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yttria-stabilized_zirconia) and [beta-alumina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-alumina_solid_electrolyte). Basically there are holes in the crystal structure which let oxide (or other) ions move. I'd say though that it's difficult to predict whether it's a conductor without knowing the system.